# Permission denied for unix socket mounted in docker container as volume

Tags: nginx, docker, php-fpm, unix-sockets

I try to containerize my nginx running currently on my server. For this I created the following docker compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    group_add: ["33"]
    volumes:
      - "/etc/nginx-docker:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro"
      - "/run/php:/run/php"
      - "/var/www:/var/www:ro"
    ports:
      - "8111:80"
      - "8443:443"
```

Everything works fine but the problem is, that I still have php-fpm's running "natively" (not dockerized) on my host system and I want to use their sockets for my nginx container (hence the line `volumes: - "/run/php:/run/php"`).

The sockets' permissions are `srw-rw---- www-data:www-data`. Therefore I added the container user to the group 33 (which is www-data on my host system -> `group_add: ["33"]`). When I check in the container the group ids, the id `33` is indeed added to the currently logged in user:

```
/ # id -G
0 1 2 3 4 6 10 11 20 26 27 33
/ # id -u
0
/ # whoami
root
```

Nonetheless when I call a website powered by PHP I get in the nginx logs following error message:

```
2024/01/21 08:58:53 [crit] 21#21: *1 connect() to unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.192.68, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock:", host: "op---s:8111"
```

Any hints or solutions what could be missing to make it work?

Comment: On what distribution are you running (Fedora/Ubuntu/...)? If you're on a RHEL-derivative, is SELinux enabled (what is the output of `getenforce`)?

Comment: @larsks I‘m on Debian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done some digging :)

If you enter the container running the nginx image, you can see that there's a couple of nginx processes running:

```
docker exec -it 43b5b971c433 /bin/sh

/ # ps -ef |grep nginx
    1 root      0:00 nginx: master process nginx -g daemon off;
   21 nginx     0:00 nginx: worker process
   22 nginx     0:00 nginx: worker process
   23 nginx     0:00 nginx: worker process
   24 nginx     0:00 nginx: worker process
   42 root      0:00 grep nginx
```

Some are run as `root`, and some as `nginx` user.

You have added the user `root` into the `www-data` group inside your docker-compose file, but even without doing that, root user should have all the permissions necessary to access the php unix socket.

You can test permissions with the `test` command. Output the exit code to see if the command has succeeded or not. As you can see, root user can read the socket file, but not execute it:

```
/run/php # whoami
root
/run/php # test -r  php8.1-fpm.sock; echo $?
0
/run/php # test -x  php8.1-fpm.sock; echo $?
1
```

So the `permission denied` error probably comes from the `nginx worker` process, run as `nginx` user.

Let's check the permissions for the files inside docker container first ...

`ls -al` gives the following output:

```
srw-rw----    1 xfs      xfs              0 Jan 25 08:58 php8.1-fpm.sock
```

saying that the socket file is owned by the "xfs".
A quick look at the `/etc/group` file inside the container shows the ID of the `xfs` group being `33` - same as the ID on the host machine for the group `www-data`.

Inside the container, you can add the nginx user to the xfs group:

```
addgroup nginx xfs
```

The problem should be fixed now.

I'm not sure how to add this directly into your compose file (how do you specify which user to add to the group?) - but you could do it in your Dockerfile if you can make a new image.

After restarting the container, the permissions seem to persist, though.

Comment: If I add the xfs group to the root user and the nginx user and restart the container it indeed works. But I would prefer to not write my own Dockerfile for this.

Comment: I mounted a bash script into /entrypoint.d/ of the nginx container where I run the two `addgroup` commands and it seems to work.

Comment: I see - that's a good idea. Unless there's a command that works in docker compose for modifying (specified) users and their groups, I think you're stuck with bash scripts or Dockerfiles. Also, does it work with adding the xfs group to nginx user only?

Answer (score 1):

Determine the user and group that PHP-FPM is running as on the host. You can usually find this information in your PHP-FPM configuration file (commonly located at /etc/php/7.x/fpm/pool.d/www.conf)

Then update your docker-compose and add this

```
user: "your_php_user:your_php_group"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Everything works fine but the problem is, that I still have php-fpm's running "natively" (not dockerized) on my host system and I want to use their sockets for my nginx container (hence the line volumes: - `"/run/php:/run/php"`).

This isn't possible or sensible.

Docker spawns its own network namespace, so you get your own firewall stack, IP stack and Unix network stack.

Even if you fix the permissions issue, lets say for example you login to the container manually with `docker exec` and `chmod` the socket file 666 and for the sake of brevity lets assume there are no user namespaces in the way too..

What you're asking to do is the equivalent of:

1. Running a `php-fpm` instance on `system1` with a Unix socket on `/var/run/php-fpm.sock`
2. Exporting the `/var/run` path over NFS on `system1`.
3. Mounting `system1:/var/run` on `system2`. A completely separate system.
4. Trying to `connect()` to said Unix socket socket on `system2` and expecting `system1` to respond with `php-fpm`.

The way you should actually do this (should actually *want* to do this, which is a separate matter) is to listen on the `php-fpm` instance using IP -- so binding it to `host_system:12345` for example. Then using `nginx` in `container` to connect to `host_system:12345`.

---

This is all just wrong. Dont listen to me.
If you create a well-named unix socket, exposed in either namespace and the path is shared between both namespaces, connecting to that unix socket connect to the other namespace!

https://lore.kernel.org/all/4C1733BE.6070708@openvz.org/T/

This patch specifically addresses it. Clearly when I tested this was a long long time ago! :)

The only time this doesn't appear to be the case is in the anonymous Unix socket creation case however that one is a pretty linux specific and not often used feature of unix sockets.

Comment: I would prefer sockets for performance reason. I've seen tutorials on the internet where they actually use sockets. But maybe they all were between a php-fpm docker container and a nginx container and not between a host php-fpm and a nginx docker container. Is it possible to do what I want by using a php-fpm docker container instead of running php-fpm natively on the host?

Comment: Personally I'd run the `php-fpm` instance in a pod associated with the nginx container. They will live in the same network namespace. Pods are a kubernetes/podman thing though.

Comment: Connecting via unix sockets means the connection doesn't have to go through the network stack. Not sure what happens if you connect to unix socket on the host system inside a docker container, but if you compare unix socket vs "localhost", sockets have less overhead.

Comment: @GChuf what happens if you cant do that. You're running two different network stacks.  A container stack and a host stack. See `man 7 network_namespaces` in any recent distro.

Comment: @MatthewIfe I think you might not be quite right there... it is possible, as far as I know that is exactly how Docker in Docker works. You can issue docker commands from within a container and have docker daemon on the host execute them by bind-mounting the socket from the host to the container.

Comment: @Marcel I dont imagine it works like that, rather its done with a `setns` call. Do you have the relevant documentation/link?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/extensions-sdk/guides/use-docker-socket-from-backend/

Comment: There are plenty of documented cases of people running docker commands on the host by bind-mounting the socket to a container and running docker buildx from a container, for CI/CD processes, for instance: https://www.kenmuse.com/blog/docker-from-docker-in-alpine-dev-containers/

Comment: @marcel I tried and tested, you're totally right! Providing the sockets path is not in the anonymous space, this really is valid. The more you know!

Comment: There's one use-case tho that I'm not really sure how they pulled it off, on MACOS the socket has an absolute path but it's restricted per user. So I'm guessing some kind of `setns` as you mentioned where two users simultaneously on the macos would maybe have two distinct namespaces and a completely isolated docker experience.